# How to convert an integer to a list in python?

Tags: python

I have an integer object for example a = 1234 and I want to convert it to a list, so it would look something like [1234].

I tried converting it into a string first and then converting it to a list but that gives me [1,2,3,4].
Any suggestions?

Comment: Your title and your question text are completely different. Do you want a list or a string?

Comment: Why do you need to convert it to a string first? Just `[a]` will make a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just cover it in brackets.

```
a = 1234
print([a])
```

Or `append()`

```
b = []
b.append(a)
```

output

```
[1234]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to convert in to string, use `str()`

```
>>> str(1234)
'1234'
```

If you are trying to put your int in a list, use `[]`:

```
>>> var = 1234
>>> [var]
[1234]
```

or do:

```
>>> l = []
>>> l.append(var)
>>> l
[1234]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
a = 1234
lst = []
lst.append(a)

print(lst) #[1234]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just cover it with brackets:

```
a=1243
a=[a]
```

or create a *list* and append *a*

```
b = []
b.append(a) # or you could do b=[a]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends. If you need the int to be a single member of a list then [a] works. If you need each digit in the integer to be an individual member of the list then list(str(a)) will work for you.